# Компактное расположение фигур SVG в ограниченных рамках

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

Рисую фигуры в таком формате:

```
    <?php
header ('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
header ('Content-Disposition: filename=example.svg');
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>
<svg version=\"1.1\"
     baseProfile=\"full\"
     xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" 
     xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"
     xmlns:ev=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events\">
    <g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\">\n";

        $x1=20; $y1=20;
        $x2=100; $y2=100;

            echo "<line stroke-width=\"1\" x1=\"$x1\" y1=\"$y1\" x2=\"$x2\" y2=\"$y2\"/>\n";

                .......

    echo "</g></svg> \n"; ?>
```

Нужно расположить фигуры максимально компактно в ограниченные рамки, допустим 200х300px не изменяя их масштаб(пример на фото). Размер и форма фигур при каждом выполнении скрипта разный.
Возможно ли это в принципе? И если да, то в какую сторону думать? Это проще на PHP, на JavaScript?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет связи с ЯП, это [математическая](https://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/download/3027/2743/)/[геометрическая](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Bundling-Three-Convex-Polygons-to-Minimize-Area-or-Ahn-Alt/39c6caa529ff9e79f8b6d29be4119d106ab6d495) [задача](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS092577211500111X&psig=AOvVaw0WWNVdHBoWOFOnRmK6fN1K&ust=1631268850278000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCIDd4KDU8fICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD).